# How can I run hp-systray from gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb, hplip

I would like to be able to run `hp-systray` from `gdb` to get a stacktrace and help fix a very annoying [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/632066) that's been around for a while now. However, if I try to run

```
gdb hp-systray 2>&1 | tee ~/gdb-hp-systray.txt
```

as per the Ubuntu Wiki's [article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Backtrace) on getting a backtrace, I get the following output:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-0ubuntu1) 7.4
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
"/usr/bin/hp-systray": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

Furthermore, using `gdb`'s `run` command returns the following:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program:  
No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.
```

Running `hp-systray` on its own in the terminal works as expected, so how can I get it to run from `gdb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hp-systray` is a python script, so try:

```
$ gdb --args python /usr/bin/hp-systray
```

Comment: Thanks much! I also added on the `2>&1 | tee ~/gdb-hp-systray.txt` bit from above and it still worked perfectly fine.